# While loop String

Tags: python

So I created a while loop and I was wondering why it still continues even if I enter an integer rather than a string. I was hoping it would stop working as I put 'str' infront of raw_input

I'm new to Python so some help would be great!

```
Answer = ""

while Answer != "Me":

    Answer=str(raw_input("Who is fantastic? : "))
    if Answer != "Me":
        print "Try again mate!"
    else:
        print "Yay!"
```

Comment: Is this your actual code? I tried running it and got `IndentationError`.

Comment: "even if I enter an integer rather than a string" - enter an integer where?

Comment: why wouldn't it continue? `str(any_integer) != 'Me'` will always evaluate to `True`...

Comment: Your `while` loop will stop when you enter `Me` (after correcting indentation)

Comment: It is, I tried to indent it on here but it went a bit wrong! It does run, and it works but I mean if I enter a number as an answer to the question it still continues. I was hoping it would only need characters to work?

Comment: If you're asking "why doesn't `str(raw_input())` crash if the user types in a number, such as '42'?", it's because there's no rule that says strings aren't allowed to contain digits. If you want an error to occur when the user enters numbers, you'll have to check for them yourself.

Comment: It doesn't matter what you enter. Everything is treated as a string. If you enter 85 that will be '85' != 'Me'

Comment: Go read some about `while` loop and come back!

Comment: I was wondering why the variable can be left empty at the beginning  of my code. I'm working through a book but there's no mention of why it can be left empty?  For all other while loop statements and working with integers or else they are assigned values.

Comment: It's only empty on entering the loop, and if the user enters the empty string. You coerce input to `str`, so if the user enters a string of digits the comparison will just compare the `str` of those digits to `"Me"`, find them unequal, print `"Try again mate!"`, and loop again.

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement should be exact below to the "answer = input("Who is fantastic?: ")" statement. If you don't then it will give you IndentationError.

Try below code:

```
answer = ""
while answer != "Me":
    answer = input("Who is fantastic?: ")
    if answer != "Me":
        print ("Try again mate!")
    else:
        print ("Yo!")
```